# xfce4-terminal less sign to start less

Tags: xfce4-terminal, less

In zsh on macOS if I want to see a text file I can use: `< file.txt`. Is the same thing possible in xfce4-terminal?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  I have a Mac sitting right here and `< file.txt` does nothing in iterm2.  However, if I do `less < file.txt` that works.  `less < file.txt` also works in the `xfce4-terminal` that way just fine.

Comment: Ok, I think it has nothing to do with iterm2 but it has something to do with zsh. < file.txt will open file.txt in less in zsh (on my machine at least).

Comment: You can install and use `zsh` via `sudo apt install zsh`.  Then you can run `chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh username` to set your shell to `zsh` but it does require a logout and login, or a reboot.

Comment: Yeah this is probably the easiest solution, thanks.